# triggering the function onchange of value in hidden input field

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a hidden input field whose value changes on certain scenario. I want to trigger a function on the change of value in that input field. (onchange function is not getting called in the same.)

is there any way to do the same in the pure javascript. ?

```
<input type="hidden"  id="securityQuestionAnswerDate" value="" data-bind="label" name="securityQuestionAnswerDate" onchange="populateSecurityQuestionAnswer(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: Why not find where the field is changed and add your code there?

Comment: @mplungjan Actually that is a option tag from which the data is getting populated

Comment: On what event? onchange of the select?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes on the change of select. Meanwhile I have taken your advice on the same by triggering the function when select's onchange event gets called.